# Unable to drag two added elements through DOM to different locations

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I'm trying to create a kanban (trello-like) simple website to learn javascript. I have gotten the drop-and-drag functionality to work, I am, however, struggling to add a new card, and move multiple cards to different locations within different lists.

The first card (which is implemented in the HTML from scratch, and not added by DOM), works fine. I can move this card wherever I need to.

I have two problems with my code:

1. I created two functions called `addCard()` and `addTaskContainer()` to be able to add a new task. The element gets created, but whenever I try to move this card, the first, original card, gets moved to the dropped position, and not the DOM created one.
2. If I try to add multiple cards through the `addCard()` function, the just seem to stack inside the same div. I realize that I need to remove the initial added ID, but I am struggling to do so while being able to add a new ID if the button is pressed again.

I want the lists containing the different cards to always have +1 task container available for a newly added card.

I have tried setting `addTaskContainer()`'s `id = "";` in the `addCard()` function, but are then unable to add it back to the `addTaskContainer()` when clicking the button.

I have also tried looping through card in cards like so:

```
for (const card in cards) {
    card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}
```

and card of cards like so:

```
for (const card of cards) {
    card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}
```

without luck.

## html

```html
<div class="lists">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="list-header">
              <p>Backlog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="list-body" id="backlog">
              <p>body</p>
              <div class="taskContainer">
                  <div class="card" draggable="true"> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="taskContainer">
                   <div class="card" draggable="true"> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="taskContainer">
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="list-footer">
              <p>footer</p>
              <button onclick="addCard()">Add ned card</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

## javscript

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
const taskContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.taskContainer');

// card listeners
card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);

// Loop through taskContainer boxes and add listeners
for (const taskContainer of taskContainers) {
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}

// Drag Functions
function dragStart() {
    this.className += ' hold';
    setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'invisible'), 0); //set timeout so card wont dissapear
}

function dragEnd() {
    this.className = 'card';
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className += ' hover';
}

function dragLeave() {
    this.className = 'taskContainer';
}

function dragDrop() {
    this.className = 'taskContainer';
    this.append(card);
}

//add card function
function addTaskContainer() {
    var taskContainer = document.createElement('div');
    taskContainer.className = "taskContainer";
    taskContainer.id = "add-new-card";
    document.getElementById("backlog").append(taskContainer);
}

function addCard() {
    addTaskContainer();
    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.className = "card";
    card.id = "new-card";
    document.getElementById("add-new-card").appendChild(card);
    document.getElementById("new-card").setAttribute('draggable', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were two problems with the code you posted:

- You were using `id` to identify element, there can only be one element with each `id` on the page. This means when you got the element by `id` it may be an old card. One way would be to remove the id when you're done dragging, but a simpler way is the store the card in a variable `draggingCard`
- You weren't adding the listeners to newly created `cards` and `taskContainers` in your functions.

I also added some styling to make everything easier to see:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwqpKg

HTML:

```
<div class="lists">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="list-header">
            <p>Backlog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="list-body" id="backlog">
            <p>body</p>
            <div class="taskContainer">
                <div class="card" draggable="true"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="taskContainer">
                <div class="card" draggable="true"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="taskContainer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-footer">
            <p>footer</p>
            <button onclick="addCard()">Add ned card</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;

    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.card-dragging {
    display: absolute;
}

.taskContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    background: skyblue;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 16px;
    min-height: 16px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
const taskContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.taskContainer');

var draggingCard = null;

// card listeners
cards.forEach(addCardListeners);

// Loop through taskContainer boxes and add listeners
taskContainers.forEach(addContainerListeners);

// Drag Functions
function dragStart(event) {
    this.className += ' hold';
    setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'invisible'), 0); //set timeout so card wont dissapear
    draggingCard = event.target;
}

function dragEnd() {
    this.className = 'card';
    draggingCard = null;
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className += ' hover';
}

function dragLeave() {
    this.className = 'taskContainer';
}

function dragDrop() {
    this.className = 'taskContainer';
    this.append(draggingCard);
}

//add card function
function addTaskContainer() {
    var taskContainer = document.createElement('div');
    taskContainer.className = "taskContainer";
    taskContainer.id = "add-new-card";
    addContainerListeners(taskContainer);
    document.getElementById("backlog").append(taskContainer);
    return taskContainer;
}

function addCard() {
    var container = addTaskContainer();
    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.className = "card";
    card.id = "new-card";

    card.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    addCardListeners(card);
    container.appendChild(card);
}

function addCardListeners(card) {
card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

function addContainerListeners(taskContainer) {
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    taskContainer.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nicole! It worked like a charm. What would be the best way to remove unused taskContainers, but at the same time always have at least one in each list (prepared for cards)?

Comment: @DanielK When a card is moved, you could check if it's taskContainer's container has more than one empty container and remove it. This should get you started `taskContainersInSection = card.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".taskContainer");`

Answer (score -1):

Part of the reason is that your drop handler is only designed to deal with the very first card on the page. `this.append(card)` will always append that first card to the drop zone. You need to retrieve the dragged element and append that element instead.

As you will observe in the MDN example, in the drag start event handler a global variable is set to identify which element is dragged. Then, later that "dragged" element is appended to the dropzone.

[MDN Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fyv61xdq/)

Relevant code:

```
    var dragged;
    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      dragged = event.target;
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
    }, false);
```

```
    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
      // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
      event.preventDefault();
      // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
      if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
        event.target.style.background = "";
        dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
        event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }
    }, false);
```

and here is one that does what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/vyr7ewbs/2/